# Is there a way for a process to find out that it's been orphanned in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

E.g.

```
make_orphan() ->
  P = spawn(...),
  ok
.
```

Is there a way for P to receive a message some time after make_orphan returns? Or is P destined to haunt the system (using up precious resources) for all eternity, unless it exits on its own?

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way to:

> receive a message some time after make_orphan returns

is with a [monitor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id85118).

```
make_orphan() ->
  Parent = self(),
  P = spawn(fun() -> monitor(process, Parent), ... end),
  ok
```

P will then get a `{'DOWN', Ref, process, Parent, Reason}` message when Parent dies. Even if Parent exits before [`monitor/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) is called, the message will contain the reason `noproc`.

Comment: I think that only works if Parent is not long-lived.

Comment: Why would that be the case? Monitors do not 'expire'.

Answer (score 0):

Communicate P to some process somewhere, register P in some way (register, global, gproc, pg2, some homebrew solution, etc.), have someone monitor it, etc. So sure, several ways. But a fundamental principle of an OTP program is that *every* process belongs to a supervision tree somewhere, so this becomes less of a problem.

Unless you are modeling a system that falls way outside the assumptions of OTP (like peer supervision among cellular automata) then you don't ever want to create the opportunity for orphans to exist. Orphan processes are the Erlang equivalent to memory leaks -- and that is never a good thing.

For some background information on some of the implications of writing OTP processes versus raw Erlang stuff where you're much more likely to leak processes, read [the documentation for `proc_lib`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html) and [the "Sys and Proc_Lib" chapter](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html) of [the OTP Design Principles docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html).

Comment: Re leaks: yeah, this is exactly why this would be useful. Process can be like, "nobody is ever going to ask me to do anything again, because nobody has a way to address me.". Without orphan detection, you have to be careful to exit every process, which is pretty annoying, and seems error-prone. Supervision doesn't seem to help: supervisors respawn processes, not exit them.

Comment: The stuff you mention in the first paragraph would not tell you that a process is not reachable anymore. Some of those things ensure that it will always be reachable (e.g. register).

Comment: @allyourcode Supervisors *do* kill processes. Some time spent writing a few toy OTP applications in conjunction with doc diving or reading LYSE might be enlightening.

Comment: I've read a decent chunk of LYSE. So far, I've only seen supervisors used to restart processes. Shutdown only seems to be done when the supervisor itself is shut down.

Comment: @allyourcode Keep reading... Also, you may not be familiar with this, its from the Erlang/OTP documentation (useful stuff to refer to every so often): http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#terminate_child-2 Consider children may be supervisors, and that different types of supervisors and can deal with different sorts of child-process supervision scenarios and...